# Save and Retrieve Image file on Windows Phone 8 (using SQL Server Compact)

Tags: sql-server-ce, windows-phone-8

Can anyone give me an example that I can store and retrieve image files on WP8.

It seems that SQL Server Compact only supports Byte[] data type?

So I have to convert BitmapImage and Byte[] to achieve this purpose?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SQL database to store an image seems like an overkill to me. I'd suggest you to use IsolatedStorage instead, and store image as a file. Internet is full of examples on how to achieve that, take a look [here](http://windowsphonegeek.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage---read-and-save-images) for example.